# Snowflake Copy Error due to field enclosed with double double quotes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Found character 'B' instead of field delimiter ',' File 
While trying to load

`123,""BigB" - some data", 345 ....`

I tried tackling this with `ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '"'` file format parameter and able to load without any errors but with few defects.

1) The particular field got loaded as BigB" - some data (double quotes in the mid of the field not trimmed).
  2) Some other fields format got messed up because of file format `ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '"'`.

Any idea or recommendation to over come this scenario in SnowFlake?

Comment: You may need to escape double quotes with another set of double quotes. """BigB"" - some data"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY to your File format.